# Auto-import sass partials in every stylesheet configutation

Tags: css, webpack, sass, next.js, css-modules

Recently I have started working with NextJS using CSS Modules. To remove repetition I would like to auto-import partials with mixins, variables, etc. in every stylesheet.

Working with GatsbyJS I found I  way how to auto-import some specific SASS partials in every stylesheet in my project. Settings looked like this:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
  options: {
  data: '@import "_reset.scss", "_typography.scss", "_mixins.scss", "_extends.scss", "_themes.scss";',
  includePaths: [
    'src/styles/partials',
    ],
  },
},
```

Right now my next.settings.js looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");

const partials = [
  "_reset.scss",
  "_variables.scss",
  "_themes.scss",
  "_typography.scss",
  "_mixins.scss",
  "_extends.scss",
];

module.exports = withSass({

  cssModules: true,

  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias["components"] = path.join(__dirname, "components");
    return config;
  },

});
```

If it possible, how can I auto-unclude partials in every stylesheet?

---

Solution to the problem, thanks to @eric-tan reply:

All partials was imported in one "_utilty.scss" partial, that was included in sassLoaderOptions:
-> data: importing the partials itself;
-> includePaths: where the imported partial is located.

```
const path = require("path");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");

module.exports = withSass({

  cssModules: true,
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    data: '@import "_utility.scss";',
    includePaths: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "styles/"),
    ]
  },

  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias["components"] = path.join(__dirname, "components");
    return config;
  },

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use sass loader like this:

```
  {
     // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and include the partial files before compilation
     loader: 'sass-loader',
       options: {
         data:
           '@import "foo-partial";\n ' +
           '@import "bar-partial";',
           includePaths: [
             path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/styles')
           ]
        }
  }
```

and nextSass provide [sass loader option](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-sass#with-sass-loader-options), you can try to combine them in your setting.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of sass-loader the above approach stops working as the data option is no longer supported.  Instead of:

```
options: {
  data: `@import "${__dirname}/sass/variables";`,
}
```

Use:

```
options: {
  additionalData: `@import "${__dirname}/sass/variables";`,
}
```